# Using Simple Injector with Castle Proxy Interceptor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm using Simple Injector in my asp.net mvc 4 project.

I can't figure out how can I use Simple Injector with castle proxy interceptor.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's in fact a [section about Interception](https://simpleinjector.org/aop#interception) in the Simple Injector [documentation](https://simpleinjector.org/documentation) that pretty clearly describes how to do interception. The code samples given there don't show how to work with Castle DynamicProxy, but you actually need to change a few lines of code to get this working.

If you use the [Interception Extensions code snippet](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/InterceptionExtensions.html), to get it working, you only need to remove the `IInterceptor` and `IInvocation` interfaces, add a `using Castle.DynamicProxy` on the top of the file, and replace the generic `Interceptor` with the following:

```cs
public static class Interceptor
{
    private static readonly ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();

    public static object CreateProxy(Type type, IInterceptor interceptor,
        object target)
    {
        return generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(type, target, interceptor);
    }
}
```

But at a minimum, this would be the code you need to get interception working with Castle DynamicProxy:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
using SimpleInjector;

public static class InterceptorExtensions
{
    private static readonly ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();

    private static readonly Func<Type, object, IInterceptor, object> createProxy =
        (p, t, i) => generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(p, t, i);

    public static void InterceptWith<TInterceptor>(this Container c, 
        Predicate<Type> predicate)
        where TInterceptor : class, IInterceptor
    {
        c.ExpressionBuilt += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (predicate(e.RegisteredServiceType))
            {
                e.Expression = Expression.Convert(
                    Expression.Invoke(
                        Expression.Constant(createProxy),
                        Expression.Constant(e.RegisteredServiceType, typeof(Type)),
                        e.Expression,
                        c.GetRegistration(typeof(TInterceptor), true).BuildExpression()),
                    e.RegisteredServiceType);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is how to use this:

```cs
container.InterceptWith<MonitoringInterceptor>(
    type => type.IsInterface && type.Name.EndsWith("Repository"));
```

This allows intercepting all interface registrations which name end with 'Repository' to be intercepted with a transient `MonitoringInterceptor`.

Comment: really nice, but I need to find way to test. many static methods and no mocking.