# Simple Injector Transaction Handling

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I am migrating my project from Spring.Net to Simple Injector. In Spring.Net, there is a concept of having several functions nested under a single transaction using transaction decorator. The functionality of the Transaction decorator was to Rollback the transactions (including the DB inserts/updated) on Error across nested functions / service functions which would have a DB call individually.

Is there any equivalent in Simple Injector?

### Sample Code of Spring.NET below

User Service

```
  [Transaction(TransactionPropagation.Required)]
    public bool RegisterUser(UserModel)
    {
    //Insert User DB Call
    int result = _Userrepository.UserInsert(UserModel);
    _subscriberservice.InsertSubscriber(UserModel);

}
```

Subscriber Service

```
    public bool InsertSubscriber(UserModel);
    {
    //Insert Subscriber DB Call
    int result = _subscriberrepository.SubscriberInsert(UserModel);

}
```

If the Insert Subscriber Service Insert fails, the User Insert also has to Roll back

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aop.html) about decorator in Simple Injector.

Comment: Please show the code you are currently using with Spring.NET to achieve this.

Comment: Added sample code..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The preferred method of doing this using Simple Injector, is to apply Decorators around your classes, as explained [here](http://simpleinjector.org/aop#decoration).

Spring.NET, however, uses a different approach, called dynamic interception. It generates Decorators for you on the fly at runtime that will be injected with interceptor classes you created.

Simple Injector has no built-in support for dynamic interception, but this can be added, as explained [here](https://simpleinjector.org/aop#interception-using-dynamic-proxies). This [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513530/using-simple-injector-with-castle-proxy-interceptor) describes how to integrate Simple Injector with Castle Dynamic Proxy, which is the framework Spring.NET uses under the covers as well.